# Nano c.nanorc format

Tags: colors, sublime-text, nano

I like portability between systems and I was trying to make my `nano` editor look as much as possible like Sublime Text (on Linux Mint). I want to color function names too. So far I managed to make it as shown in the picture:

[image: Sublime Text and nano side-to-side]

The code I used is a bit of a cheat. I color `void` itself and the space after until the next space:

```bsh
color brightyellow  start="void " end="[ ]"
color cyan "void"
```

The reason I color it twice is that it makes `void` bright yellow too, plus it works only if I write my code like:

```bsh
void fu (void);
```

with a space between `fu` and `(`.

However, if I write the code as:

```bsh
void fu(void);
```

it breaks.

My question is how do I write `start="void " end="("` in `c.nanorc`, in such a way to start from `void` to `(` but ignore the words themselves?

Comment: Why don't you just install Sublime on the second box, if that's what you normally use?

Comment: nano is for Raspberry PI Zero with LITE OS. On lite os you dont even have desktop, its all done via ssh

Comment: As many programming languages only allow alphanumeric characters and only a few special chars, (`_`), you can use a simple regex on the function identifier like `color brightyellow  "void [a-zA-Z0-9_]+"`. For more flexibility, you want want to replace the space with `[[:space:]]+`. And for the `end="("` you need to escape the `\(`. Although "a little bit" late, maybe someone might find this helpful...